# Kubeflow: How to supply a file as pipeline input (param)

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

From what I understand, a Kubeflow python only takes string parameters, but in case of the pipeline I need, the user should be able to supply a file as input. How can I do that?
Best

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to upload the file to some remote storage (HTTP Web server, Google Cloud Storage, Amazon S3, Git, etc) and then "import" the data into the pipeline using a component like "Download from GCS".

Comment: Is it somehow possible that I upload the file to the pvolume somehow? Because if that's possible then I can create a web ui and the user will directly upload the file through the UI, and th UI will then upload it the pvolume, rather than downloading from a GCS.

Comment: Your UI can upload the file to HTTP-accessible place (e.g. GutHub gist) and then you can give the URL to the "web/Download" component which will "import" the data to the Pipelines.